# Path during configure via a variable

Tags: bash, configure

I am installing a software package using configure, make and make install.

How can I specify the install directory path at configuration as a variable. I currently use

```
./configure=<full-path-to-src>/install
```

I want to define this path as a variable and then use it instead of putting up the entire path here something like this.

```
PATH=<full-path-to-src>
./configure --prefix=$PATH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't use `PATH` as the variable name - that's reserved for your shell's executable search path, and overwriting it will cause lots of problems.

Second, the standard option for setting the installation path is `--prefix` (with two dashes, not one).

Third, you should get into the habit of quoting variable expansions in order to prevent them from word-splitting by the shell.

So:

```
mypath=full/path/to/src
./configure --prefix="$mypath"/install
```

Comment: Thanks, My intention was not to use PATH as variable name, this was just and example. One dash instead of two is a type that I've corrected.

Comment: Additionally, the "full path to _src_" implies installing it somewhere in the source directory, which may not be what's actually intended. Usually, one would use `$HOME/local` or `/usr/mystuff` or similar.